# How to remove a word from Aspell's British dictionary

Tags: gnu, spell-checking, aspell, ispell

When I check my texts with `aspell` (with the British dictionary), the word "**froward**" is accepted (because it is a [real English word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/froward)). However I never use it, so in *my* texts "**froward**" is always a misspelling of "**forward**". Therefore I want `aspell` to reject "**froward**".

How can I remove a word from Aspell's standard dictionary? Is there a way to create a "blacklist" of words? There is no way to mark it in  `.aspell.en.pws`, because the personal dictionary only contains a "whitelist".

Comment: Why not dump the standard dictionary to a file, remove the required words and use the modified/custom dictionary rather than the original one?

Comment: @jtlz2 Sounds sensible, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Aspell does not support it.

Submit an issue or a pull request on the [official repo](https://github.com/GNUAspell/aspell) if you care.